# Input field readonly to users but still editable via DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, input, readonly

I have an input field like so:

```
<input type="text" id="23" value="Something" readonly />
```

I have the input element readonly because I don't want users to be able to edit the field value.

However, what I *would* like is to be still able to manipulate the value of the element via the DOM e.g:

```
getElementById('23').value="Something else";
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `getElementById('23')`? you mean `document.getElementById('23')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure it is: but you will need to do so https://jsfiddle.net/pz1yd11u/

```
document.getElementById('23').value="Something else";
```

You were missing the `document`

(IDs and class names should never start with a number: [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html))

**Update after comment, with click event to change the input value**

https://jsfiddle.net/pz1yd11u/1/

```js
document.getElementById("kevs-button").addEventListener("click", displayNewValue);
  
function displayNewValue() {
 document.getElementById('23').value="Something else";
}
```

```css
#kevs-button {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}
#kevs-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="23" value="Something" readonly />

<div id="kevs-button">Button</div>
```

Comment: I don't think I explained myself very well :)

What I need to do is change the value on an event (click, hover whatever). I understand I can use document.getElementByID() when the document loads but I need to be able to do it with an event.

PS - thanks for the link about using numbers as IDs.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I only just got the reply notification email - it did, yes, I've accepted your answer :)